# php application fails to detect the right temp directory

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel 9 application running on AWS EC2, I'm trying to upload a file.

The action fails with this message: **File could not be uploaded: missing temporary directory.**

Inside my loaded `php.ini`, I have it set as `upload_tmp_dir = /tmp`

But when I do a `phpinfo`, I see the value for `upload_tmp_dir` is empty. Looks like whatever value I add for upload_tmp_dir is not read/recognized by php.

I used `echo sys_get_temp_dir();` to get the path that the app is using, and it returns as:

`/var/www/html/tmp`

What's the reason the app is failing to detect the right path to the tmp directory?

If it matters, here are also the directory permissions:

/tmp is owned by root/root and is drwxrwxrwt+

everything under /var/www/html (where the app is) is owned by ec2-user/apache

Comment: In linux doesn't `/tmp` mean the tmp directory who's parent directory is the root of the drive

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I believe so

Comment: Did you try `upload_tmp_dir = /var/www/html/tmp`

Comment: Although, I am not sure I would place my tmp dir there under the html dir which is available to the world

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just added an update to the question. Looks like whatever value I added for `upload_tmp_dir` is not recognized by PHP. `phpinfo` always shows it as no value.

Comment: Then run a `<? phpinfo(); ?>` and check the forst page of the output for the value for `Loaded Configuration File` It sounds like you are changing the wrong `php.ini` file

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved this issue:

- Edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service`. Set `PrivateTmp=false`
- Edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service`. Set `PrivateTmp=false`
- Reload parameters: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
- Restart service: `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm` and `sudo systemctl restart httpd`